# Word for when someone enforces a rule on some occasions but not others

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

If you have a set of rules that no one follows due to lack of enforcement, but on rare occasions when a rule is broken, out of convenience for the rule maker, they enact discipline for breaking that rule?

Comment: They could be said to be ***making an example*** of the person breaking the rule, but that's more common when the rules are usually stringently followed and the person being disciplined is being used to show what happens when the rules are broken to keep everyone else in line. It could still be used in this context as that's kind of what they're doing; punishing someone else to deter the others from stepping out of line. Probably not 100% appropriate though since the rules aren't usually enforced.

Comment: @JohnClifford Yeah, that does sound kind of right, but I was thinking a word that implied the ruling was somehow unfair or out of spite.

Comment: Posted as an answer and deleted the comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Duly noted and added.

Comment: 'Double standards' has a **very** strong connotation of unfairness and bad use of authority. So much so that it should probably be avoided if they are not present (though Wikipedia gives the general, unmarked sense. It does go on to add a large caveat.)

Comment: Discrepant and selective come to time as being included in noun phrases to go with a suitable noun. Like "discrepant ruler" or a "selective rule enforcer"

Comment: @DannyRodriguez The legal term of art in the US is *selective prosecution*, considered a violation of due process and equal protection guaranteed by the Constitution.  So in this context, *selective enforcement* would be appropriate.

Comment: This is exactly how government works in my country =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given that you're looking for a rule that's enforced for some people but not for others, the most appropriate description for this is a [***double standard***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-standard):

> a ​rule or ​standard of good ​behaviour that, ​unfairly, some ​people are ​expected to ​follow or ​achieve but other ​people are not
>
> *Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

As Edwin Ashworth pointed out, the definition on [***Wikipedia***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_standard) is more general, and may suit your needs better:

> A double standard is the application of different sets of principles for similar situations.

Comment: This answer would be is very close, but since the op stated that it is used on some occasions but not all occasions, it disqualifies the term "double standard".

Comment: @DannyRodriguez The rule is either enforced for some people, or not enforced for others. Doesn't that fit the definition of a rule that some people are unfairly expected to follow but others aren't?

Comment: @Danny Rodriguez Incorrect. 'Double standards' means 'the application of different sets (not just a single set) of principles [in] similar situations'. It could be two sets of principles [prosecute / turn a blind eye] applied to 300 situations [people doing 79mph in a 70 zone]..

Comment: But the application of enforcing a rule is not due to the type of person but by the situation or setting in which it occurred, and so making it not really a type of discriminatory occurrence but more arbitrary.

Comment: Your definition of double standard is different from what the MW and Oxford dictionary defines it to be.

Comment: MW: *a set of principles that applies differently and usually more rigorously to one group of people or circumstances than to another;*. How does that not apply to "a group of people who were chosen at random" and "everyone else"?

Comment: @Danny Rodriguez The broader Wikipedia definition covers inconsistency of enforcement of laws for most reasons (vindictiveness in a particular case, laziness in most cases, incompetence, arguably discretion ...). // 'Your' definition of 'double standard' may well be the narrower one, but that doesn't mean it's the only one used. This has been covered.

Comment: But the constitution or essence of the group does not motivate the more rigorous treatment of that group, it's the situation and the convenience of the enforcer.

Comment: @Danny Rodriguez Applying principles more rigorously to a group doesn't necessary require that the reason for the application was any attribute of the group itself.

Comment: If the op is writing an academic paper, I can respect the Wiki definition. In informal dialogues or speech or professional, I would go by the MW definition.

Comment: No but the majority uses of the term Double Standard pervade discussions and speeches when discrimination was clearly evident, like racial or sexist speech. And since all definitions are dictated by the context in which they are used, including all relative factors, the aspect of discrimination must be included in its uses.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez I still can't see how the MW definition doesn't fit this. **a set of principles** *(the rules)* **that applies different and usually more rigorously** *(in one case offenders are disciplined, in the other they are not)* **to one group of people or circumstances than to another** *(we have two groups: the people who were chosen at random to whom the rules were deemed to apply; and everyone else, who is not expected to comply with the rules and is not punished for breaking them)*.

Comment: Simply because the decision of the enforcer to follow up on a rule and punish those who violated the rule is arbitrary enough not to be based on race or gender or anything like that but determined upon the situation and the convenience of the enforcer. A police officer who doesn't give me a speeding ticket because he just got laid is motivated not to do so by his sheer mood and it can't be said that he's enacting a double standard.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez I don't think you can apply the same logic here. The exceptions to the rule in this context are made because the rulemaker felt like applying them intermittently on a regular basis. It's not a case of them deciding not to apply the rules as a one-off because something good happened. That's not the same thing at all, IMO, but I appreciate your input on this.

Comment: I became so tired of this I did some more digging, and found a term I wasn't aware existed. A general term, with a Wikipedia article covering the different causal factors. But  I doubt many would use 'selective enforcement' in preference to 'double standards' here.

Comment: "A double standard is the application of different sets of principles for similar situations.", this is a better description of what the word/term I am looking for describes.  "Selective enforcement", now I've read the description is also valid for another use case.

Comment: Talking about this term or terms and definition was fun and intriguing. I think mostly because we've all experienced this. When i think if the reverse, of someone who enforces rules 100% of the time, I think of Stannis Boratheon from Game of Thrones whose live and the lives of his family were saved by a caring ship merchant who smuggled in food for him and his family to eat while they were under siege, and yet, despite saving his family by smuggling, Stannis still punished him for smuggling in that food since smuggling was a crime.

Comment: Here's [an example](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/7626902/scott_pilgrim_vs_the_world_2010_wallace_s_ultimatum/) of its usage in pop culture.

Answer (score 27):

The general term is **selective enforcement**. This covers situations where there are different reasons (some morally better / more justifiable than others) behind what on the surface may appear inconsistent practice.

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_enforcement):

> In law, selective enforcement occurs when government officials such as
>   police officers, prosecutors, or regulators exercise enforcement
>   discretion, which is the power to choose whether or how to punish a
>   person who has violated the law. The biased use of enforcement
>   discretion, such as that based on racial prejudice or corruption, is
>   usually considered a legal abuse and a threat to the rule of law.
>
> In some cases, selective enforcement may be desirable. For example, a verbal warning to a teenager may effectively alter his behavior without resorting to legal punishment and with the added benefit of reducing governmental legal costs. In other cases, selective enforcement may be inevitable. For example, it may be impractical for police officers to issue traffic tickets to every driver they observe exceeding the speed limit, so they may have no choice but to limit action to the most flagrant examples of reckless driving.

Comment: Although the term "Double Standards" is more applicable for my use case "Selective Enforcement" is also useful, so thank you.

Comment: As is often the case with SWRs, I'm saddened by the relative number of upvotes here for an answer that, while being appropriate and having needed a bit of digging to find, is hardly fundamental to English usage, and hardly likely to be useful to many enquirers. Contrast this with John Lawler's far more valuable answer to 'Can “where” ever be used as the subject of a relative/adjective clause?', 2 upvotes at the moment.

Answer (score 20):

You could say that enforcement of the rules is wholly ***arbitrary***

> **Arbitrary**
>
> 1. not fixed by rules, but left to one's judgment or choice; discretionary:
>
>    *arbitrary decision, arbitrary judgment*
> 2. based on one's preference, notion, whim, etc.; capricious:
>
>    *young children and their arbitrary rules for games*

<sub>[Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/arbitrary#Tuo15Vs6KrfMpImy.99) Copyright © 2010 by Wiley Publishing, Inc., Cleveland, Ohio.</sub>

Comment: This is the word that sprang immediately to my mind, and as long as the OP's scenario doesn't involve clearly-recognisable patterns (e.g., (dis-)favouritism), I'd say it fits the best.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard this described as capricious, even though it doesn't exactly fit the definition.

> **ca·pri·cious**
>   given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behavior.
>   "a capricious and often brutal administration"

For example, ["arbitrary and capricious grading"](http://www.umuc.edu/policies/academicpolicies/aa13080.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

This happened quite frequently in the military.  Often, there was some obscure rule or regulation that nobody cared (or even knew) about, but was applied vigorously to the "slackers" or "goof-offs" or those thought to be disrespectful.  We called it an "*attitude adjustment*".  It was intended to correct other, often completely unrelated behavior that those in charge did not like but could otherwise do nothing about.

This definition from [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Attitude%20Adjustment) describes it, the last part "let them know their place" seeming to be the most frequent reason.

> The act of correcting a person for their inappropriate actions, for
>   stepping over the line, to show your dominance over them, or to let
>   them know their place

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are **wishy-washy** informally.

> **Wishy-washy**
>
> someone or something uncertain, indecisive and wavering, or someone who cannot make up their mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would say simply ***that the rule is randomly enforced***.

Comment: Wouldn't call it "random" if it's only enforced when advantageous to the enforcer.  That word implies that it could be good or bad for all involved with equal probability.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You are probably right. In which case it is enforced at the random discretion of the authority concerned.